# Fetching image file from database and display to Rails website using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

I'm a beginner in Ruby on Rails, and Database stuff. I am having a hard time figuring out how to fetch image file from Sqlite3 , and PostgreSQL database and paste/display that image properly into my website using Ruby on Rails, or Ruby on Rails.

And my problem is "how to fetch images from database and then properly display those images to my website using Rails", just that.

I started by pasting image file from my local computer to the `<%= @real_estate.image %>` image input form in my Rails website and then as I view the image from the website, I see something

useless like `#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000000d4fb548>` in my `show.html.erb` webpage and then the colorful picture that I placed doesn't show up.

What am I missing? Is there anything I need to add to my Controller files?

If you want to have a look inside my `app/controllers/real_estates_controller.rb`, where I believe the image should be controlled, here it is:

```
class RealEstatesController < ApplicationController 
  before_action :set_real_estate, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /real_estates or /real_estates.json
  def index
    @real_estates = RealEstate.all
  end

  # GET /real_estates/1 or /real_estates/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /real_estates/new
  def new
    @real_estate = RealEstate.new
  end

  # GET /real_estates/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /real_estates or /real_estates.json
  def create
    @real_estate = RealEstate.new(real_estate_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @real_estate.save
        format.html { redirect_to @real_estate, notice: "Real estate was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @real_estate }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @real_estate.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /real_estates/1 or /real_estates/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @real_estate.update(real_estate_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @real_estate, notice: "Real estate was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @real_estate }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @real_estate.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /real_estates/1 or /real_estates/1.json
  def destroy
    @real_estate.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to real_estates_url, notice: "Real estate was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_real_estate
      @real_estate = RealEstate.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def real_estate_params
      params.require(:real_estate).permit(:offer_type, :object, :land_area, :floor_area, :town_and_province, :bedroom, :bathroom, :carport, :image)
    end
end
```

Or `app/controllers/real_estates_controller.rb` isn't the case here? And it is in another file?

My `show.html.erb` file:

```
<div class="container">
  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

  <p>
    <strong>Offer type:</strong>
    <%= @real_estate.offer_type %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Object:</strong>
    <%= @real_estate.object %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Land area:</strong>
    <%= @real_estate.land_area %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Floor area:</strong>
    <%= @real_estate.floor_area %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Town and province:</strong>
    <%= @real_estate.town_and_province %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Bedroom:</strong>
    <%= @real_estate.bedroom %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Bathroom:</strong>
    <%= @real_estate.bathroom %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Carport:</strong>
    <%= @real_estate.carport %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Image:</strong>
    <%= @real_estate.image %>
  </p>

  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_real_estate_path(@real_estate) %> |
  <%= link_to 'Back', real_estates_path %>
</div>
```

I guess `<%= @real_estate.image %>` in `show.html.erb`is wrong for displaying pictures ??